# Error Parsing JSON data on executing PHP script

Tags: java, php, android

this is my php script

```
<?php
try{

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pfe'/*info db*/,'root'/*login*/, ''/*mdp*/);

}

catch (Exception $e)

{

die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());

} 

$msg = $_GET['msg'];
$mail = $_GET['mail'];

$result = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO message ( `msg`, `mail`) 
      VALUES ('{$msg}', '{$mail}')");
$result->execute();
if($result == true) {
echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
}

else{

echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}
```

my script i think is good cause i tried it with my browser it works but with android does not insert the data
and this is java class,

```
EditText msg,mail;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

public void signup(View v) {
    String message = msg.getText().toString();
    String email = mail.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(this, "wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Insertinto(this).execute(message, email);

}


public class Insertinto extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;

    public Insertinto(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String msg = arg0[0];
        String mail = arg0[1];

        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String result;

        try {
            data = "?msg=" + URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");
            data += "&mail=" + URLEncoder.encode(mail, "UTF-8");

            link = "http://192.168.43.93/dysfonction.php" + data;
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

this is json

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String jsonStr = result;
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

when i execute it show me "Error parsing JSON data" i didn't find where is the pbm.

Comment: you should also post the json data

Comment: validate your json first using something like jsonlint.com .It seems like your json is in invalid format.

Comment: `"Error parsing JSON data."` is thrown for a JSONException. I suggest you try to see if the message string that is being received by Android is good.

Comment: this is the problem but the message seems good @DebosmitRay

Comment: can you try to hard-code `String jsonStr = "{\"query_result\":\"SUCCESS\"}"` as a string in Android and see if it works as expected?

Comment: it show me "Data inserted successfully" but in my data base it doesn't enter still empty @DebosmitRay

Comment: In that case, there is some issue with the string being echo-ed by the php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the place of

```
result = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

use

```
result = bufferedReader.readLine().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

debug and check the result received in the postExecute(); and from next time paste the logcat as well..

Comment: and how is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this to

```
if($result == true) {
echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
}else{
echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}
```

this

```
if($result == true) {
   $data = array(
       'query_result' => 'SUCCESS'
   );    
}else{
   $data = array(
       'query_result' => 'FAILURE'
   );    
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

It seems to be your java code is so clear. So sent response from php code like above may be works.

Comment: the same thing @Prabakaran

Comment: Error parsing JSON data @Prakaran T

Comment: try a demo from postman and see what you got either error or correct result.  let’s check the API with Postman .                https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Comment: that's what i got {"query_result":"SUCCESS"} @Prakaran